# List header/section color becomes dark while scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I am using the this code to have section/headers in list.
http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-sectioned-headers-in-listviews/

I am setting the color with 50% alpha to list header and my window background color is transparent. So while scrolling header color becomes dark. Any idea how to overcome this.
and i have also set android:cacheColorHint="#00000000".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I set the background color of the header view to the same background colour as the list's parent and it worked.

- So I had a LinearLayout with a background colour of 'grey'.
- The list is contained within this layout.
- The list had android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" set in the XML and no background colour set.
- The header view is loaded using LayoutInflater, inside my activity and set before the call to the list's setListAdapter.
- The parent View (or main View) of the list header was also a LinearLayout with a background colour of 'grey'.

Hope this works for you.